# Overlay histograms in one plot

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have two dataframes that I'm trying to make histograms of.  I would like to overlay one histogram over the other and show them in the same cell, so I can easily compare the distributions.  Can anyone suggest how to do that?  I have example code and data below.  This will plot the histograms separately one above the other.

Data:

```
print(df[1:5])

 bob
1 1
2 3
3 5
4 1
```

print(df2[1:5])

```
 bob
1 3
2 3
3 2
4 1
```

Code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    %matplotlib inline

    df[df[bob]>=1][bob].hist(bins=25, range=[0, 25])
    plt.show()
    df2[df2[bob]>=1][bob].hist(bins=25, range=[0, 25])
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ax`:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

df = pd.DataFrame([1, 3, 5, 1], columns=["bob"], index=[1, 2, 3, 4])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([3, 3, 2, 1], columns=["bob"], index=[1, 2, 3, 4])

ax.hist([df, df2], label=("df", "df2"), bins=25, range=[0, 25])
ax.legend()
```

Comment: Thank you, I think that did the trick.  So what it looks like this does is plot the two histograms in the same plot, in two different colors, the bar for each bin right next to each other?